# How many convex quadrilaterals can be formed between two parallel lines where 5 points lies in one line and 7 in the other?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

My approach to solve this problem has been first choose all the possible combinations of 4 points from the 12 available. Which is,

$^{12}C_4=\frac{12!}{4!8!}=495$

Then, since they have to be convexed I get rid of all of the four collinear points. Which are,

$^5C_4=\frac{5!}{4!}=5$ and $^7C_4=\frac{7!}{4!}=210$

So I have that, $^{12}C_4-(^5C_4+^7C_4)=495-(5+210)=495-215=280$

So there are 280 convexed quadrilaterals, but, should I get rid of the 3 collinear points too? If I do it I got,

$280-(^5C_3+^7C_3)=280-(10+35)=280-45=235$

Thank you in advanced for any help on the matter.

Comment: What is a "convex quadrilateral" in this game? Do you mean strictly convex?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Yes.

Comment: $^7C_4=\frac{7!}{4!3!}=35$

Comment: And if you must take this approach, you want $^{12}C_4-(^5C_4\,^7C_0 +^7C_4\, ^5C_0) - (^5C_3 \,^7C_1+^7C_3\, ^5C_1)$

Answer (score 4):

In order to have a strictly convex quadrilateral we have to select $2$ points on one line and $2$ points on the other line:
$$\binom{5}{2}\cdot \binom{7}{2}=210.$$
Following your approach you should have: $$\binom{12}{4}-\Big(\underbrace{\binom{5}{1}\binom{7}{3}+\binom{7}{1}\binom{5}{3}}_{\text{$3$ on one line and $1$ on the other}}+\underbrace{\binom{7}{4}+\binom{5}{4}}_{\text{$4$ on a line}}\Big)=210.$$

Comment: Why I got more with my method? Shouldn't be the same answer since I'm subtracting the collinear points?

Comment: Following your approach you should have: $495-(5\binom{7}{3}+7\binom{5}{3}+\binom{7}{4}+\binom{5}{4})=210$.

Comment: Why would you multiply 5 by $\binom{7}{3}$ and 7 by $\binom{5}{3}$?

Comment: $5$ ways to select a point on the line with $5$ points and $\binom{7}{3}$ to select three points on the other.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

> So there are 280 convexed quadrilaterals, but, should I get rid of the 3 collinear points too?

The person who set the question may disagree with me, but I would consider a "quadrilateral" with three collinear points to be a triangle and not a quadrilateral.

> If I do it I got,
>
> $280-(^5C_3+^7C_3)=280-(10+35)=280-45=235$

No. Given three collinear points, you need to count *all* sets of four points which contain them.

Comment: 1. Answer. Yes, because they are collinear. 2. Answer: so there is no need to substract more combinations? So there is indeed 280 posible quadrilaterals?

Comment: 1. I'm not sure what you mean. "*Yes*" what? Yes, it's a triangle? Yes, it's a quadrilateral? Something else? 2. You need to subtract *more* combinations. In particular, you need to weight that ${}^5C_3$ by something and that ${}^7C_3$ by something.

Comment: Yes. I do agree in your first part that it is a triangle.